# Targeting three.js on div and not on html or body. cause a 2px gap on the height

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know is a stupid question but this is important for me, the first problem I have is when I set the div target always I have 2px space on the bottom of the page How I can solve this problem

#### I have this screenshot ass you see there is a gab on the bottom I try to add -2px on height but is not working

[image]

### style.css

```
.canvas_3d {
    width: calc(100vw - 300px);
    background: purple;
    height: calc(100vh - 2px);
}
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div (window:resize)="onResize($event)" id="canvas_3D" class="canvas_3d"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### app.ts

```
// The target 3d container.
  container: any;

  /**
   * The 3D canvas Width & Height
   */
  w: any;
  h: any;

  // Scene, Camera and Rendered variables.
  scene: any;
  camera: any;
  renderer: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.init3D();
  }

  init3D() {

    this.container = document.getElementById('canvas_3D');

    this.w = this.container.clientWidth - 2;
    this.h = this.container.clientHeight - 2;

    console.log('W: ', this.w);
    console.log('H: ', this.h);


    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, this.w / this.h, 0.1, 1000 );

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setSize( this.w, this.h );
    this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    this.scene.add( cube );

    this.camera.position.z = 5;

    this.createMesh();


    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );

      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };

    animate();

  }
```

Comment: why do you use `height: calc(100vh - 2px);` instead of `height: 100vh;` in your style?

Comment: If I use height: 100vh I have the same output. 

I have tried different combinations the best solution I get is when I remove all -2px from all files and I add on css overflow:hidden

Comment: Try setting `canvas { display: block; }`